# Can any one tell me how to delete my Profile?

Tags: discussion, user-accounts

I would like to delete my Stack Exchange profile. Can any one tell me how?

Comment: In any case, here we go: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5999/how-can-i-delete-my-account

Comment: You don't need to delete. Just take break from it come back later whenever you feel like it. We'd be sorry to see you go. :)

Comment: I would like to tell you that deleting your account (as I understand it), will probably delete all your votes (unless you have made a whole lot of them). (Please correct me if I am wrong other users). As such, several people will lose lots of reputation. If you just take a break, this won't happen (probably even if the break is forever).

Comment: Yes, I'd probably be one of those people. :)

Comment: @Jonah - Never fear. It;s unlikely they'll delete his account. They'll de-register it if there's useful content.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[This post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5999/how-can-i-delete-my-account) on Meta Stack Exchange describes the process. Basically, since you have more than one post or have voted, you need to contact the Stack Exchange team [here](https://stackoverflow.com/contact).

Comment: see you Guys..Good luck..

Comment: why is it so hard to delete a Profile on this site?????

Comment: @RANSARA009 - Partly to prevent people from quitting without good reason and erasing all their votes. Which - although I am doing my best to provide you with the information you need - probably would happen to me. Specifically, I've answered 9 of your questions. If you voted all of them up, I will lose 90 reputation (not sure what happens to the accepted points). I'm sure you've voted for other posts of mine too.

Comment: @RANSARA009 you do realise that even if you delete your account, all your questions and answers remain, just under the name 'Community'? Just change your profile name... you have the potential to become an even-more valued member of this community.

Comment: @RANSARA009 because once it's posted the community takes partial responsibility for maintaining them,  but also they become part owned. Any one  might be relying on your answers.

Comment: does any one know how to find Your profile link?

Comment: @RANSARA009 - Here's yours on Meta: http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/users/64716/ransara009. And here's yours on the main site: http://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/64716/ransara009

Answer (score 6):

### Process

As Jonah has pointed out, if you wish to delete your account you need to contact the SE team using the ["Contact Us](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/contact)" link, which can also be found below.

### What happens next?

Given that you've accrued a reasonable amount of votes for your questions (as well as voting up and down on a number of questions), it's quite likely that your account won't be destroyed, it'll just be deregistered. That means your questions, comments and votes will remain on the site, just under an account not linked to your personal info and no longer under your control.

### Reasons for quitting

You seem to be rage-quitting after finding out that copying questions over from moviemistakes verbatim isn't acceptable conduct. This was an honest mistake and something that's quite easily fixed. **Don't quit**, or, at the very least take a few days to think about it.

For the record, turning these into acceptable questions (by attributing the content) is a very simple process that takes about one minute per question. If you do quit, I'll be working my way through your questions and correcting them.